# Incorrect AND/OR priority in query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

Today I found weird behavior of elasticsearch 1.5.2

I'm indexing 2 documents:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/index/type {
    "string":"a b"
}

POST http://localhost:9200/index/type {
    "string" : "c d"
}
```

And following query returns no hits (why?):

```
POST http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query_string" : {
                "query" : "string:a AND string:b OR string:c AND string:d"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the same query with brackets over ANDs returns 2 documents, as expected:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
            "query_string" : {
                "query" : "(string:a AND string:b) OR (string:c AND string:d)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to specification
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

> NOT takes precedence over AND, which takes precedence over OR

so both queries **must** return same result.

Is it bug or I've missed something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query mentioned by you

```
"query" : "string:a AND string:b OR string:c AND string:d"
```

works as all a,b and d should be present in `string` and if c is present then that document will be boosted up .

That's why it looks for a,b and d which it doesn't find in any document and displays no result.

As per the specification [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-query-string-query.html):

> AND and OR can affect the terms to the left and right.

You can also refer [this](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Query-string-operators-seem-to-not-be-working-correctly-td4055615.html)